# Django How to Have an Internal Link on Custom Button Component

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am on DjangoCMS 3.11.3. I am *not* a Django developer, I primarily do .Net but was asked to help out with CSS and HTML. That went well, so now we are here...

We currently have an imported Bootsrap4 Link/Button component that has far more options than the PM wants and than what the end users need.

This imported plugin has 2 levels to the Internal Link and the 2nd level is hierarchical (indented) as show below:

[image]

I seem to be able to have an internal link created in my custom Button component, but it only has a single dropdown of pages (each has a duplicate for some reason, the values of th duplicates are different if that means anything) and they are *not* indented (hierarchical) at all.

[image]

I have been googling and such with no real success. I was able to dig into the repos and such to get some of the source code but it was getting insanely deep how far the spaghetti code was going. This is where you come in. I just want a simple component that lets the user pick a page within the CMS. I understand why all of the inheritence and such is helpful, but I just want the one or two properties that I really need in my component.

Here is the models.py:

```
class CustomButton(CMSPlugin):
  link_is_optional = True

  name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_('Display name'),
    blank=True,
    max_length=255,
  )
  
  internal_link = models.ForeignKey(
    Page,
    verbose_name=_('Internal link'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    help_text=_('If provided, overrides the external link.'),
  )
```

Here is my cms_plugins.py:

```
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class CustomButton(CMSPluginBase):
  model = CustomButton
  name = _('Custom Button')
  module = _('Custom Plugins')
  render_template = 'cms_plugins/button.html'
  cache = False
  allow_children = True
```

These give me that flat dropdown list.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.